# how to remove object from JS array based on values from second array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Hey guys I'm trying to remove all objects from an array that matches the values from a second array. Allow me to explain with some examples!

```
var originalObj = [
{"id":"88","name":"Lets go testing"},
{"id":"88","name":"Have fun boys and girls"},
{"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"},
{"id":"99","name":"Have fun boys and girls"},
{"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"},
{"id":"99","name":"Have fun boys and girls2"},
{"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"}
]
```

Currently with my javascript code I can only remove ONE specified value from object and any occurrences with said value

```
var updatedObj= $.grep(originalObj , function(e){ 
             return e.id!= '88'; 
        });

console.log(updatedObj)
[
    {"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"},
    {"id":"99","name":"Have fun boys and girls"},
    {"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"},
    {"id":"99","name":"Have fun boys and girls2"},
    {"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"}
]
```

What I want to accomplish is have the .grep function look up a second array that looks something like this.

```
 var filterID = ["88","99"];
```

so the result should look something like this

```
//Needs updating
//var updatedObj= $.grep(originalObj , function(e){ 
//           return e.id!= '88'; <-- needs to match all filterID values instead
//      });

console.log(updatedObj)
[
    {"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"},
    {"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"},
    {"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"}
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate over all the values in your array and filter that way.

```
var updatedObj = originalObj;
for (var i in filterID) {
  updatedObj = $.grep(updatedObj , function(e){ 
    return e.id!= filterID[i];
  });
}
```

Comment: If it's overwriting it every time, the value in that current iteration would be stripped out each time, resulting in all values stripped out by the end of the iteration...

Comment: Yea i see that now, sorry

Answer (score 2):

If you use an object to represent the list of keys to filter this becomes simple:

```
var toRemove = {
    88: true, 99: true;  // keys significant, values thereof irrelevant
};

var updatedObj = $.grep(originalObj, function(e) { 
    return !(e.id in toRemove);
});
```

For short arrays this is about the same efficiency as a doubly-nested loop, that being approximately `O(n * m)`, where `n` is the size of the array being filtered and `m` is the number of elements to remove).

However if the array of values to filter is substantial then this will be `O(n)` (assuming that the `in` operator performs in constant time)

Answer (score 0):

use the `indexOf` array function

```
var filterID = ["88","99"];
var updatedObj= $.grep(originalObj , function(e){ 
    return filterID.indexOf(e.id) === -1; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over all the values in your array and filter that way.

```
           var updatedObj = [
                {"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"},
                {"id":"99","name":"Have fun boys and girls"},
                {"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"},
                {"id":"99","name":"Have fun boys and girls2"},
                {"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"}
            ],
            filterId = ["89","99"],result=[];
            $.each(updatedObj,function(index,item){
                if(filterId.indexOf(item.id) === -1){
                   result.push(updatedObj[index])
                }
            })
            console.log(result);
```